# Custom Enter and default arrows key press events in contenteditable div at the same time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, contenteditable, keydown

I want to trigger an event on Enter press inside of contenteditable div, while avoiding default Enter behavior (creating new line) and keeping arrows functional at the same time.

Whatever I try, either Enter is disabled and arrow keys functional, or vice-versa.

The catch is to achieve this for one class of contenteditable divs - `.a` - while keeping arrow keys disabled for everything else in the document.

**http://jsfiddle.net/opr2ouzo/**

```
$(document).on('keydown',function(e){ //disables keys
    console.log(this, e.target);
    var key = e.charCode || e.keyCode;
    if(key == 13 || key == 32 || key == 33 || key == 34 || key == 35 || key == 36 || key == 37 || key == 38 || key == 39 || key == 40 ) {
        e.preventDefault();
    } else {};
});
$('.a').on('keydown', function(e) { //enables arrows for this class
  e.stopPropagation(); 
  var key = e.charCode || e.keyCode;
    range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0)
    post_range = document.createRange();
    post_range.selectNodeContents(this);
    post_range.setStart(range.endContainer, range.endOffset);
    next_text = post_range.cloneContents();

    if( next_text.textContent.length === 0 && key == 39 ){
        e.preventDefault();
    }
    else if( next_text.textContent.length === 0,1 && key == 13 || key == 32 || key == 33 || key == 34 || key == 35 || key == 36 ){
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
function checkPosition(){};

kd.run(function () { //fires keydrown plugin
    kd.tick();
});

$('.a').on('mouseenter', function(){ //css change as example event on Enter press while the caret is in this class
    kd.ENTER.press(function(){
        $('.bg').css('background','skyblue');
        console.log();
    });
});
```

Here is the whole pipe regarding this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

The fix is actually pretty simple, either modify code like in this fiddle - remove `document` part, edit selectors and make custom key events for each class separately - either in more complex cases with multiple key press events - keep `document` part and disable only those keys which are not disabled in `.a` or overwritten successfully by key press events. Also, custom keypress events should be manually unbound inside the `a` part.

http://jsfiddle.net/opr2ouzo/2/

```
$('.a, .b').on('keydown', function(e) {
  var key = e.charCode || e.keyCode;
    range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0)
    post_range = document.createRange();
    post_range.selectNodeContents(this);
    post_range.setStart(range.endContainer, range.endOffset);
    next_text = post_range.cloneContents();

    if( next_text.textContent.length === 0 && key == 39 ){
        e.preventDefault();
    }
    else if( next_text.textContent.length === 0,1 && key == 13 || key == 32 || key == 33 || key == 34 || key == 35 || key == 36 ){
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
function checkPosition(){};

kd.run(function () {
    kd.tick();
});

$('.a').on('mouseenter', function(){
    kd.ENTER.press(function(){
        $('.bg').css('background','skyblue');
        console.log();
    });
});
```